# Get current environment name

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In Phoenix Framework, how can I get the current environment's name ?

I've already tried reading `env` variables with `System.get_env("MIX_ENV")`, but the value is not always set.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

**`Mix.env()` doesn't work in production** or other environments where you use compiled releases (built using Exrm / Distillery) or when `Mix` just isn't available.

---

**The solution** is to specify it in your `config/config.exs` file:

```elixir
config :your_app, env: Mix.env()
```

You can then get the environment atom in your application like this:

```elixir
Application.get_env(:your_app, :env)
#=> :prod
```

---

**Update (March 2022):**

Recent versions of Elixir (v1.13.x+) recommend using `config_env()` instead of `Mix.env()`, so do this:

```elixir
config :your_app, env: config_env()
```

Comment: To elaborate on this, Mix is a build tool and not something that the application logic is dependent upon, that's why it does not make sense to include Mix in binaries.

Comment: Would `config :your_app, env: config_env()` be an equivalent alternative?

Comment: Yes, in the most recent versions of Elixir, `config_env()` is recommended.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [**`Mix.env/0`**](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.html#env/0):

```
iex(1)> Mix.env
:dev
```

Comment: This won't work in application code, during runtime, in production.

Comment: `Mix` is not available in a compiled production app, so `Mix.env` inside any code that runs in that environment will cause the following error: `(UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function Mix.env/0 (module Mix is not available)`

It's a much better idea to use Sheharyar's answer.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to putting the `Mix.env/0` into your applications configuration is to use a module attribute. This also works in production because module attributes are evaluated **at compile time**.

```
defmodule MyModule do
  @env Mix.env()

  def env, do: @env
end
```

If you only need the environment in a specific place - for example when starting up the application supervisor - this tends to be the easier solution.

Comment: setting the environment inside of config is a much cleaner solution, also now in most cases you would go for runtime configuration.

Comment: Or with a macro which is similar like in `if unquote(Mix.env == :dev), do:`.

Answer (score 1):

Now in each environment config file (e.g. `prod.exs`) generated by default, you'll see the environment atom being set at the last line:

`config :your_app, :environment, :prod`

You can then use `Application.get_env(:your_app, :environment)` to get it.

You can do the same in any custom environment config you create.