# Get current environment in Phoenix (Elixir)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

in Ruby on rails we can call `Rails.env` to fetch current ENV. (or `Rails.env.development?`)

I was wondering if Phoenix Elixir has similar standard built in to (Functional of course)

I know I can do `System.get_env("MIX_ENV") == "dev"` I'm just checking if there is more standard way (I couldn't find anything in documentation or existing SO)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35010950

Comment: I would recommend Sheharyar's answer to that question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44747870/320615.

Comment: thank you that's perfect ;)

Comment: FWIW: `Rails.env` does not fetch anything, `Rails.env` is a method returning a plain old good `String` (extended with some methods, though.) Specifically `Rails.env` has nothing to do with `ENV`.

Comment: Also, I would say that if you need to check the environment in runtime, you are likely doing something wrong.

Comment: this is just for the database seed file ... I just want to crate few different records than production seed file, ...and yes I could create separate file for that it's just the difference is so trivial it's better to keep it in same file and check ENV

Comment: @mudasobwa  thank you for reply but you are wrong about the `Rails.env` being "plain string"  it's returning extended string object  `Rails.env.class   # => ActiveSupport::StringInquirer `  ..I'm not expecting Phoenix to return object or anyting I just wanted to see the best practice convention

Comment: You possibly could take a look at what this class is: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/498370c05b56ae02189466420da117b32304ddf9/activesupport/lib/active_support/string_inquirer.rb It’s a plain old good string, that [in the very weird way] allows to use `.blah?` instead of `== "blah"` through `method_missing` (just because we can, yes.) There are no more differences. So yes, it **is** a plain string.

Comment: I think both of us are talking about same thing just the naming is causing confusion in our discussion. Here's the thing when you say "plain string" that means a String  that means this is plain string: `"development".class == String`.  Now you can monkey patch or extend directly the class `String` and  it's extended String. Now `Rails.env`  is `StringInquirer` which effectively evaluates a String but **it's different class** so it's not a `String` string, it's definitely not plain String. But yes I agree with your points, it's just a Class that does String evaluation around this convention.